# 1. Let the curves represented by the three degree polynomials f(x) g(x) and h(x) meet at points A and B. Find the value of f(10)

Tags: function

Let the curves represented by the three degree polynomials f(x) g(x) and h(x) meet at points A and B. Given that

g(x) = x ^ 3 - 9x ^ 2 + 20x

h(x) = x ^ 3 - 7x ^ 2 + 10x

f(2) = 2g(2)

3f(7) = g(7)

Find the value of f(10) (MCQ)

Answer: 200

So the answer given is 200 but I am getting 300. Can anyone explain how the answer is got.

Comment: Welcome! It seems you better ask at https://math.stackexchange.com/ as this question is not related to programing.